# What's the best way to access my networked Linux home directory inside WSL?

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a lot of Linux infrastructure running in my homelab. User home directories live on a dedicated NAS VM that exports them over NFS and SMB. I'd like to share that same home directory with my WSL, but all of the options seem to suck a little in one way or another.

**WSL 1:**

WSL 1 apparently does not have CIFS or NFS in its custom kernel, so they can't be used at all. I've done a lot of searching, and as far as I can tell, there's no solution for this aside from "switch to WSL 2". You can use drvfs, however, to mount a shared folder from Windows into a WSL distro. Unfortunately, when you do that for your home directory [horrible problems ensue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8121). I've tried both mapping the network drive and just using the share directly. There's also annoying permission issues like all files being set to `0744` which means ssh won't use my keys.

**WSL 2:**

WSL 2 has a real Linux kernel! Yay! Except it runs as a (managed) VM. Boo! Ok it's not really that bad, except that the VM is ephemeral and gets destroyed/recreated on reboots. This really only matters because the virtual NIC gets a random IP address in a random range, rather than using the host IP. You can change it, but then you have to do it on every boot. I did find a [Powershell script](https://gist.github.com/wllmsash/1636b86eed45e4024fb9b7ecd25378ce) that I could run on startup to potentially address this, though.

Am I missing anything? Are there any easier ways to deal with this? I use WSL/Windows Terminal pretty much daily to ssh into my Linux infrastructure and to play around with various git repos (I open the files via mapped network drive in Windows then debug/run in WSL).

Comment: I'm not too familiar with WSL, but if it is running with a NATed IP, to the NFS server it would appear as if your windows machines IP is mounting the share. Also you can use hostnames in `/etc/exports`.

Comment: I would think that WSL can see and access any mounted location that Windows has, have you tried to mount these locations within Windows and access them within WSL? You can modify the random IP behavior with a script that reassigns the address.

Comment: @mashuptwice you would think so, but it still can't mount it for some reason.

Comment: @Ramhound I have. if you look at the issue I linked, it does not work for home directories. Using cifs on wsl 2 is slightly better, but you still run into permission issues.